# Adding new element into a new object and then print out the new object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

**strong text**
Hi all I am  a  newbie in JavaScript, i am stuck with this problem hopefully anyone can help out thank you . I am trying to create an Application where allow the user to input what kind of food , price that the customer have consume in a restaurant. First the User is required to key in the name of the User . Then when he or she click the" input name" button a new user object is created. I have created a constructor call UserCustomer(). when a new object is created , it will create  element inside such as  the customer name, price, and a remove user button, if the user want to remove the customer from the list.
After the User click the input name button.the user will be navigate to the Add food page. The user is required to input the food and price which the customer consume,the user can add as many as he wants, when the user click the add Food Button , the program will push the food and price enter into the new customer object created previously.

When the User Click the "done adding". the program will push all value into the array "newMakanUser".

And then finally the function will print loop through this "newMakanUser" and print out the Value

The Result i get is 
0: [object Object] 1: [object Object]

The Result that i want to get is

For Example

John  Food :Burger Fries cola  Price :2.4,1.5,1.0
Linda Food : salad Fruits juice Price : 3.5, 1.0,1,6

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//This is  a New Array
var newMakanUser = [];
var newButton  = [];
var placeHolder = [];
var TempVar=[];  
var TempUSer= "";

    
    
    
    
function UserCustomer(nameU){
    this.nameUser = nameU;
    this.Food = [];
    this.Price= [];
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Remove " +nameU +" from list ";

// 2. Append somewhere
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(button);
   
}

    
    
    

function outArray() {
        newMakanUser.toString();
        newButton.toString();
    
        function displayArrayObjects(arrayObjects,outputName) {
                    // First Check the Array Length
                    var len = arrayObjects.length, text = "";
                    this.outputName = outputName;
                   
                          //Loop through the Array

                          for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                    var myObject = arrayObjects[i];
                          //Loop through the object in side the array
                                           for (var x in myObject) {
                                            text += ( x + ": " + myObject[x] + " ");
                                                                   }
                                                           text += "<br/>";
                                                         }

                      document.getElementById(outputName).innerHTML = text;
                                                   }
  
    
    
       
                   displayArrayObjects( newMakanUser,"outputArray");
           
               
    
    
    
                      }
    
// This Function is to create an object and store it inside an array.
function addName(UserName){
    // Get the User Input Object product name
       UserName = document.getElementById("NamePax").value;
                   
            TempUSer =  UserName ;    
     
    
         TempVar.push(new UserCustomer(UserName));
         // alert( "Hello");
      //  newMakanUser.push(new myUserName(createProduct,productprice));
       slides.style.display = "block";
       slidess.style.display = "none";
       slidesss.style.display = "none";
       
    
}
    
    
function addFoodPrice(Foody,Pricey){
    
    
        Foody  = document.getElementById("FoodyName").value;
        Pricey  = document.getElementById("FoodyPrice").value;
    
     
    
          TempVar.Food.push(Foody);
          TempVar.Price.push(Pricey);
    
}
    
function doneAdd(){
    
        newMakanUser.push(TempVar);
        
        slides.style.display = "none";
        slidess.style.display = "block";
        slidesss.style.display = "block";
       // document.getElementById("outputDB").innerHTML = text;
    
}
    
 
    
// This Function will remove the unwanted object
    

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Who Order  the Food</h2>
<P> <input type="button" value="Check what you order" id="" onclick="outArray();"/></P>
<p id="outputArray"></p>
<p id="outputDB"></p>
    
<div id="slidesss" style="display:block">  
<P style="color:blue;"><strong>Person Name:</strong><input type="text" style="text-align:center; margin-left:10px;"id="NamePax" name="element"  
placeholder="Person Name" ></P>
</div>
    
<div id="slides" style="display:none"> <!-- set display to none --> 
    
<P style="color:blue;"><strong>Food Name :</strong><input type="text" style="text-align:center; margin-left:10px;"id="FoodyName" name="element"  
placeholder="Food Name" ></P>
    
<P style="color:blue;"><strong>Food Price :</strong><input type="text" style="text-align:center; margin-left:10px;"id="FoodyPrice" name="element"  
placeholder="Food Price" ></P>
    
    
    
<P><input type="button"  value="Add Food" id="Btn_Close1" onclick="addFoodPrice(this.Foody, this.Pricey );"/>
<P><input type="button"  value="Done Adding" id="Btn_Close1" onclick="doneAdd();"/>
    
</div> 
    
<div id="slidess" style="display:block"> 
<P><input type="button"  value="Input Name" id="Btn_Close" onclick="addName(this.UserName );"/></P>
</div> 

    
    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your code snippet running here so I'm not able to immediately verify my suspicions in your code, but it looks like the problem might be from your `myObject` variable in the function `displayArrayObjects(arrayObjects,outputName)`.

Make sure that `myObject` has the correct shape, i.e.

```
var myObject = {
    name: 'John',
    food: ['burger', 'cola'],
    price: [3.5, 1.1]
}
```

`myObject[x]` might also be an object or array, so that might be why you're only printing out `[object Object]`, so make sure you're iterating through every element of your object correctly. Use `console.log` to test the intermediate variables of your function to see if everything is in the correct format that you need. Hope this helps!